# Getting error Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main while executing my feature file in eclipse?

Tags: cucumber-java

I have done all configuration any thing missing in my configuration?
Feature: Access website airasia
         user should navigate the url airasia.com for flight search
Scenario: User should be access airasia flight search page
Given User should navigate airasia website
And User should click on flight button
And User should enter origin as Bengaluru
And User should enter destination as Pune
And User should select depart date as 15/12/2018
And User select one way button
When User should click on search button
Then All available flights from Bengaluru to Pune successfully apear on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add this dependency in your project and try to execute the scripts again.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```